# aspnet core mvc send user from register (post) method to login (Post)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My application has the following 2 methods

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult login(LoginViewModel viewModel){

  //user sign in logic 

 return View();
}
```

I also have a registration action method. From the following registration action method I want to fill the login view model and redirect the user to the login post action. I believe this would be a good user experience when they have registered they will be automatically signed in as well.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult register(RegisterViewModel viewModel){

  //register the user and redirect to the login post method.

  var loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel(){username : viewModel.userName,Password : viewmodel.password}
 return View();
}
```

Note, both methods are in two different controllers.

Is this possible with aspnet core? I had a look at the challenge method in aspnet core but not sure how that works.

Comment: Why make them go to the log in page at all? Just log them in and send them to whatever page you want.

Comment: Code duplication/ separation of concern .. When there is already a action method doing login's why have registration  method do the same thing?

Comment: Because they are different things. Extract the sign-in logic to a shared place if you like, but it's only a couple of lines of code.

Comment: You could look at the default individual account template it does sign in after registration. Registrations should default to a login.

Answer (score 0):

The Log-in/sign-in code should be common not in the Login post action

Usually after the registration the user is redirected to the user profile or the home page.

However, to redirect to another action and pass the ViewModel as parameter, use the following.

`return RedirectToAction("login","[ControllerName]",loginViewModel);`

And it will be HttpGet.